# Configure push notification in an iOS platform in .NET 8 MAUI

Tags: c#, ios, azure, push-notification, maui

In my .NET 8 MAUI application, I want to add the push notification using Azure Notification Hub. I have already added the code for Windows and Android, and it works, without using external components. I register the device by calling the [Azure Notification Hub API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt621153(v=azure.100)).

For example, for Android I wrote this code:

```
var firebaseToken = await FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken();
var deviceInstallation = new
{
    InstallationId = GetDeviceId(),
    Platform = "gcm",
    PushChannel = firebaseToken.ToString()
};
```

In this case the `deviceInstallation` is provided by `Firebase` because is native in Android.

My issue is when I have to write the code for iOS. Apart from the platform that I guess is `apns`, what is the `PushChannel`? I read somewhere that I have to implement the call in this function in the `AppDelegate`

```
[Export("application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:")]
public async void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, 
    NSData deviceToken)
{
    // ...
}
```

Here, I can use the `deviceToken` as the `InstallationId`. What can I use for the `pushChannel`?

Comment: Finally, I found the solution and I [wrote a post](https://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/maui/maui-push-notifications-using-azure-notification-hub-for-ios/) to explain all the steps to send and receive push notification from Azure Notification Hub in iOS

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use your solution but didn´t get it to work. But by using it and some other sources I found another solution using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.

The key part is this code

```
var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(this.connectionString,  this.notificationHubName);
var installation = new Installation
{
    InstallationId = deviceToken,
    PushChannel = deviceToken,
    Platform = NotificationPlatform.Apns,
    Tags = Array.Empty<string>()
};

await hub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);
```

deviceToken is obtained from RegisteredForRemoteNotifications. Tags is an array and can be changed by calling CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync again.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If you are interested, I created a post for the implementation https://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/maui/maui-push-notifications-using-azure-notification-hub-for-ios/